# Unexecpected Include Expecting T_STRING

Tags: php, syntax-error

I Don't Seem to see any errors with this code
Its in PHP, its trying to fetch a users "earnings" from the MYSQLI Database by mysqli_fetch_array(), But it keeps coming with this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in test.php on line 9

```
<?php
session_start();
include "mysqli_config.php";
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $getuserearnings = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $user = $mysqli->query($getuserearnings);
            $userearnings= mysqli_fetch_array($user);
            $test= $userearnings['earnings'];
echo " This is your earnings "$test" Amount";
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the error by just watching the syntax highlighting. You're not escaping the `"` in your string.

```
echo " This is your earnings \"$test\" Amount";
```

Answer (score 1):

A few options to write what you want would be like this:

1. `echo ( " This is your earnings ".$test." Amount" );` // This one uses concatenation
2. `echo ( " This is your earnings '$test' Amount" );` // this one combines different quotes. Although the result would have the single quotes also printed.
3. `echo ( " This is your earnings \"$test\" Amount" );` // this one uses scape of quotes inside the external pair of quotes
4. `echo ( " This is your earnings $test Amount" );` // this one only uses surrounding double quotes. Works due to the parser interpreting variables inside.

Output of the above examples assuming $test = 'test';:

1. This is your earnings test Amount
2. This is your earnings 'test' Amount
3. This is your earnings "test" Amount
4. This is your earnings test Amount

The third one is the same as the one mentioned by Musa. I just added the parenthesis and explanation of how it works.

Options 2 and 3 print a string with quotes, single or double. Options 1 and 4 output a clean string without quotes.

Comment: fixed the quotes, in a rush I wrote them in reverse order.